# Accessing SharePoint with Microsoft Graph using the Microsoft App Registration Portal

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to access SharePoint through Microsoft Graph using the v2.0 endpoint (Microsoft App Registration Portal) but I am unable to authenticate.

I am using the following code.

```
var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/testtest.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/", "http://localhost:61716/", new ClientCredential(password), null, null);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = cca.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var graph = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((message) =>
        {
            message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));
```

I am currently getting the error "Message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token."

How do I add the appropriate permissions to the app registration portal and how do I apply them / access SharePoint from my C# application.

Edit: I would like to clarify that I do not want to use the Azure AD, I would like to use the  [Microsoft App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2F).

Answer (score 0):

The permission need to add in your **Application project**.

```
Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All
```

If you use aspnet MVC, just modify the **GraphScopes** to in web config([get started](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start)).

If you use NetCore, just get started from the [Github sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample). Then modify the **GraphScopes** in appsettings

If you use Angular, just get started from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start),choose SDK-based or Rest-based for your requirement. Then set the **GraphScopes** in config.js

Comment: Thanks, I would like to do it using the [Microsoft App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2F) not the Azure AD. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is your C# project? If you use MVC/NetCore, just get started from the sample from official sites: or Github.  Then modify the GraphScope in webconfig or appsettings.

Comment: My C# API is connected to Angular Frontend that uses the V2 endpoint for single signon. I want to be able to configure the Application Scopes properly so I can pass that token from the UI to the API and then to Sharepoint to get sharepoint access from the API using the user scope obtained in the UI.

Comment: The frontend library is not the key. The key is your whole project is what language : MVC/NETCore/PHP/Angular or so. Just find the project config to add the needed permission.

Comment: Yes, I understand but how do you add the graph scopes to the Microsoft App Registration portal? And what is the string needed to access those scopes?

Comment: Actually，most time we just need to add GraphScopes in the project, no need to add them in the Microsoft App Registration Portal. Or you can add the same permission in Registration portal and Project. If you set the config file correctly, you don't need additional parameter in the request string, the project will add them automatic.